# Adding test coverage reporting to Angular 4 inside the dotnet core 2.0 SPA template

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, webpack-2, karma-coverage

I've created a new project using the Angular 4 template and I want to add test coverage reporting to it but I can't get it working. The tests run correctly, but in the end it looks like `karma-remap-coverage` can't generate the report because it can't find the sourcemaps. Here's the error:

```
webpack: wait until bundle finished:

webpack: Compiled successfully.
02 10 2017 10:37:22.343:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
02 10 2017 10:37:22.347:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
02 10 2017 10:37:22.370:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
02 10 2017 10:37:24.067:INFO [Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket D9FHbxYFkC9uUFrnAAAA with id 77245712
Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.28 secs / 0.173 secs)
Error: Could not find source map for: "C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\ClientApp\test\boot-tests.ts"
    at CoverageTransformer.addFileCoverage (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\src\CoverageTransformer.js:96:14)
    at C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\src\CoverageTransformer.js:223:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CoverageTransformer.addCoverage (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\src\CoverageTransformer.js:221:5)
    at C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\src\remap.js:31:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at remap (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\node_modules\remap-istanbul\src\remap.js:30:11)
    at RemapCoverageReporter.onCoverageComplete (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-remap-coverage\remap-coverage.js:23:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at InMemoryReport.writeReport (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-coverage\lib\in-memory-report.js:14:22)
    at writeReport (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-coverage\lib\reporter.js:68:16)
    at C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma-coverage\lib\reporter.js:290:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Collection.forEach (C:\Projects\insights\Src\Web.UI.Admin\node_modules\karma\lib\browser_collection.js:93:21)

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 49.97% ( 999/1999 )
Branches     : 25.31% ( 206/814 )
Functions    : 44.81% ( 220/491 )
Lines        : 50.74% ( 966/1904 )
================================================================================
(node:68684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Here are the configuration files I'm using:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false, // I changed this one to false
    "inlineSourceMap": true, // and I added inline source maps
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

a part of webpack.conf.js

```
// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                //filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.browser#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });
```

and my karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '.',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            '../../wwwroot/dist/vendor.js',
            './boot-tests.ts'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            './boot-tests.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap', 'coverage']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'remap-coverage'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        mime: { 'application/javascript': ['ts','tsx'] },
        singleRun: true,
        webpack: require('../../webpack.config.js')().filter(config => config.target !== 'node'), // Test against client bundle, because tests run in a browser
        webpackMiddleware: { stats: 'errors-only' },

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'in-memory'
        },

        remapCoverageReporter: {
            'text-summary': null,
            json: './coverage/coverage.json',
            html: './coverage/html'
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370561/adding-code-coverage-to-the-asp-net-core-angular-2-starter-application/47250706#47250706. Might help you out. Just went through all this myself.

Comment: Thanks! But we have switched to the angular-cli based template in the meantime